# inner join in linq to entities

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-entities

I have entity called Customer and it has three properties:

```
public class Customer {
    public virtual Guid CompanyId;
    public virtual long Id;
    public virtual string Name;
}
```

I have also entity called Splitting and it has three properties:

```
public class Splitting {
    public virtual long CustomerId;
    public virtual long Id;
    public virtual string Name;
}
```

Now I need to write a method that gets companyId and customerId. The method should return list of splitting that relates to the specific customerId in the companyId.
Something like this:

```
public IList<Splitting> get(Guid companyId, long customrId) {    
    var res=from s in Splitting 
            from c in Customer 
            ...... how to continue?

    return res.ToList();
}
```

Comment: In place of Splitting you have pasted Customer entity twice.. Please fix that

Comment: Why do u need Company ID in the method get... The Splitting has customer ID which can be used to make the selection based on passed customer ID

Comment: @Ankur: In order to increase security, each method that exposed by the business layer requires companyId in order to validate it effects only on its entities.

Comment: For more complete example , please reference to http://stackoverflow.com/a/9722744/900284

Answer (score 86, accepted):

```
var res = from s in Splitting 
          join c in Customer on s.CustomerId equals c.Id
         where c.Id == customrId
            && c.CompanyId == companyId
        select s;
```

Using `Extension methods`:

```
var res = Splitting.Join(Customer,
                 s => s.CustomerId,
                 c => c.Id,
                 (s, c) => new { s, c })
           .Where(sc => sc.c.Id == userId && sc.c.CompanyId == companId)
           .Select(sc => sc.s);
```

Comment: Is there a way to write it as lambda query?

Comment: If you mean linq extension methods (`Select`, `Join`... look at my edit)

Comment: What about using the Extension Methods to join on multiple columns?

Answer (score 5):

You can find a whole bunch of Linq examples in visual studio.
Just select `Help -> Samples`, and then unzip the Linq samples.

Open the linq samples solution and open the *LinqSamples.cs* of the *SampleQueries* project.

The answer you are looking for is in method Linq14:

```
int[] numbersA = { 0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9 };
int[] numbersB = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 8 };

var pairs =
   from a in numbersA
   from b in numbersB
   where a < b
   select new {a, b};
```

Comment: I never knew about getting samples directly in VS. +1

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% sure about the relationship between these two entities but here goes:

```
IList<Splitting> res = (from s in [data source]
                        where s.Customer.CompanyID == [companyID] &&
                              s.CustomerID == [customerID]
                        select s).ToList();

IList<Splitting> res = [data source].Splittings.Where(
                           x => x.Customer.CompanyID == [companyID] &&
                                x.CustomerID == [customerID]).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public IList<Splitting> get(Guid companyId, long customrId) {    
    var res=from c in Customers_data_source
            where c.CustomerId = customrId && c.CompanyID == companyId
            from s in Splittings_data_srouce
            where s.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
            select s;

    return res.ToList();
}
```