# exception when calling ToList()

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

As continue to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176192/inner-join-in-linq-to-entities), I have this method:

```
public IEnumerable<Splitting> Get(Guid companyId, long customerId)
{
    CustomerRepository customersRep = new CustomerRepository();
    var customers = customersRep.Get(companyId);
    return GetQuery().Join(customers,
         s => s.CustomerId,
         c => c.Id,
         (s, c) => new { s, c }).
         Where(sc => sc.c.Id == customerId).
         Select(sc => sc.s);
}
```

When I am doing:

```
var query=Get(someGuid, someCustomerId);
query.ToList(); //This throws an exception
```

I got the exception:

```
Unable to create a constant value of type 'MyProj.Domain.Business.Entities.Company.Customers.Customer'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.
```

What is the meen of this exception and how can I solve it?

**UPDATE:**
`GetQuery()` returns `Context.CreateObjectSet<T>()` where T in this case is `Splitting` class.
`CustomerRepository.Get(companyId)` is:

```
    public IEnumerable<Customer> Get(Guid companyId)
    {
        return GetQuery().
            Where(x => x.CompanyId == companyId).
            Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false).
            AsEnumerable().
            OrderBy(x => x.Name.IsNumeric()).
            ThenBy(x => x.Name);
    }
```

Comment: What is `GetQuery()`? Can you show the code for both `GetQuery` and `CustomerRepository.Get`?

Comment: @Alex Aza: I updated the question.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with `ToList()`. You'll get the same exception if you use `Count()` or if you iterate with a `foreach`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is your `customers` collection which you pass into the `Join` method. This collection isn't an `IQueryable` but an in-memory collection which EF will pull from the database first when your `Join` gets executed. It's an in-memory collection because you are using `AsEnumerable()` in your `IEnumerable<Customer> Get(Guid companyId)` method and then order the result. While this would work in LINQ to Objects it is not allowed in LINQ to Entities and leads to the exception you had. (If `Get` would return a collection of primitive types (like `int`) instead of a `Customer` collection it would also work in LTE, as the exception says.)

Now, I see that you need `AsEnumerable()` because of this `IsNumeric()` method in your `OrderBy()` clause which could not be translated to SQL. But do you actually need the sorting when you pass in the result into `Join`? You return finally entities of type `Splitting` and if you would want a special sorting you had to add it somewhere before the final `ToList()`.

So, what I would try is to omit `AsEnumerable()` and the sorting:

```
public IQueryable<Customer> Get(Guid companyId)
{
    return GetQuery().
        Where(x => x.CompanyId == companyId).
        Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false);
}
```

This way you have an `IQueryable`. I'd expect that this would work and the whole query including the `Join` would be executed in the database.

Answer (score 3):

You've got a deferred query there in `IEnumerable<Splitting> Get(Guid companyId, long customerId)` and I think you're trying to execute it out of scope.

Add `ToList()` to the end of your `Select(sc => sc.s)` and you should be good to go.  That will ensure the query actually gets executed before it returns.

```
public IEnumerable<Splitting> Get(Guid companyId, long customerId)
{
    CustomerRepository customersRep = new CustomerRepository();
    var customers = customersRep.Get(companyId);
    return GetQuery().Join(customers,
         s => s.CustomerId,
         c => c.Id,
         (s, c) => new { s, c }).
         Where(sc => sc.c.Id == customerId).
         Select(sc => sc.s).
         ToList();
}
```

Comment: What do you meen by "deferred query"?

Comment: Meaning that the query is evaluated when it's used, not when it's defined.  In EF for example, you can dynamically build a query across multiple methods and then execute it once when it's done, which is more efficient.  [Here's a quick overview](http://roque-patrick.com/windows/final/bbl0392.html).