# Linq select with join

Tags: c#, linq

I have a basic selection task to be carried out

```
var query = db.Candidate.Where(.....
```

but I want the where to be on another table called Tag

in sql it would be

```
select * from Candidate
join Tag on Tag.candidateId = Candidate.tagId and Tag.tagId = 7
```

Thus getting all Candidates with tag 7

Im trying to do this directly with a Where, is this possible or do I need to use Linq to SQL.

Comment: Directly its not possible. You first need to join table and then fetch data from that joint.

Comment: And I cant do db.Candidate.Where(w => w.Tag.SOMETHING

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720225/how-to-perform-join-between-multiple-tables-in-linq-lambda

Comment: @CodeCaster - Sorry if I sounded unclear, but I meant the same thing as Yuval's answer.

Comment: @Harvey sure, that's a way, but it's not impossible. See my answer.

Comment: @CodeCaster - Yeah. Yet still, you will have to perform one or the other type of inclusion/join before putting where. OP was directly going for where so that's what I replied is not possible.

Comment: @Harvey you can, if you have lazy loading enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't show the relations, but it must be possible to do something like:

```
var query = db.Candidate
              .Include(c => c.Tags)
              .Where(c => c.Tags.Any(t => t.ID == 7))
```

Just query the candidates where a candidate has any tag that has the ID you're looking for. This will be written out more or less as the SQL you show.

You can omit the `Include()` if you have lazy loading enabled.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `Join` in LINQ to do that:

```
var candidates = from candidate in db.Candidates
                 join on tag in db.Tags
                 where candidate.CandidateId == tag.TagId
                 select candidate
```

Answer (score 2):

Try doing it with .Join as shown below :-

```
var query = db.Candidate.Join(db.Tags, r => r.tagId , p => p.tagId , (r,p) => new{r.Name});
```