# How to select multiple columns in one variable in entity framework code first?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I have two tables in sql (Singer, Albums) now my query is as below

```
IQuerable<AlbumVM> = (
    from c in context.Singers 
    join d in context.Albums on c.SingerID equals d.SingerID
    select new AlbumVM()
    { 
        SingerName = c.SignerName,
        AlbumsName = d.AlbumName
    } );
```

Now suppose a singer has 50 columns,this query returns me 50 rows, then I need to iterate through it.

**I feel I am missing something here.**
Is there someway in which I can get just one record as

```
SingerName , Albums[]
```

I am using Entity framework code-first.

Comment: is that helpful or worked for you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using code first you should have a foreign key on `Albums` to `Singers`

```
public class Album
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public virtual Singer Singer {get;set;}
}

public class Singer
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public virtual ICollection<Album> Albums {get;set;}
}
```

then you would just need

```
var singers = (
    from s in context.Singers.Include("Albums")
    select s);
```

this would give you an collection of Singers and each singer would have a collection of Albums

```
foreach(var s in singers)
{
   foreach(var a in s.Albums)
   { 
      //
   }
}
```

To get the album name from `MasterAlbums` you just expand your `Include`.  It should look like this

```
var singers = (
    from s in context.Singers.Include("Albums.MasterAlbum")
    select s);
```

Then each Album would have a property of `MasterAlbum.Name`

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcApplication1.Models.Singer>
<dl>
    @foreach (var s in Model)
    {
        <dt>s.Name</dt> // Singer Name
        <dd>
            <ul>
                @foreach (var a in s.Albums)
                {
                    <li>a.MasterAlbum.Name</li> // Album Name
                }
            </ul>
        </dd>
    }
</dl>
```

Comment: Yes! People always forget to use these navigation properties.

Comment: @Jamie, thanks
Yes this is what I was looking for **but** the thing is that the Albums table doesn't have names it just have AlbumId, the Album Name is stored in other table(MasterAlbums)..now this MasterAlbums doesn't have direct relation to Singer. Singer has one to may relation with Albums and MasterAlbums have one to many  relation with Albums. So how do I fetch AlbumsName ??

Comment: i added some more info to get Album Name.  The names in the `Include` may not be the same pluralization/singularization in your case. Typically the one-to-many relationships `Albums` is plural and one-to-one `MasterAlbum` is singular.

Answer (score 1):

you can try out group join like this

[How to: Perform Grouped Joins (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397905.aspx)

```
Person magnus = new Person { FirstName = "Magnus", LastName = "Hedlund" };
            Person terry = new Person { FirstName = "Terry", LastName = "Adams" };
            Person charlotte = new Person { FirstName = "Charlotte", LastName = "Weiss" };
            Person arlene = new Person { FirstName = "Arlene", LastName = "Huff" };

            Pet barley = new Pet { Name = "Barley", Owner = terry };
            Pet boots = new Pet { Name = "Boots", Owner = terry };
            Pet whiskers = new Pet { Name = "Whiskers", Owner = charlotte };
            Pet bluemoon = new Pet { Name = "Blue Moon", Owner = terry };
            Pet daisy = new Pet { Name = "Daisy", Owner = magnus };

     // Create two lists.
            List<Person> people = new List<Person> { magnus, terry, charlotte, arlene };
            List<Pet> pets = new List<Pet> { barley, boots, whiskers, bluemoon, daisy };


var query = from person in people
             join pet in pets on person equals pet.Owner into gj
             select new { OwnerName = person.FirstName, Pets = gj };
```

Here in example owner i.e. person object is compared but in your case property will get compared

```
var query = from c in context.Singers 
            join d in context.Albums on c.SingerID equals d.SingerID into gj
             select new { SingerName = c.SingerName, Albums = gj };
```

Comment: Yes your ans is useful enough but Album table doesn't have names it just have ids, Album names are stored in another table MasterAlbums..so now can you please bit tell me how will I get the Album names matching to id in the same query..

Comment: @Chetan - than you can create one more join between album and album detail table in same query and take grou p

Comment: `var query = from c in context.Singers 
            join d in context.Albums on c.SingerID equals d.SingerID into gj
            join e in context.MasterAlbums on d.AlbumID equals e.AlbumID
           select new { } `

But I don't get d.AlbumId, it throws error **The name d doesnot exist in the left side of equals **

Comment: @Pranay..Plus Singer doesn't have any direction relation with MasterAlbums

Comment: @Chetan - try like this var categorizedProducts =
    from p in product
    join pc in productcategory on p.Id equals pc.ProdId
    join c in category on pc.CatId equals c.Id
    select new {
        ProdId = p.Id, // or pc.ProdId
        CatId = c.CatId
        // other assignments
    };  check this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720225/how-to-perform-join-between-multiple-tables-in-linq-lambda for multiple join

Comment: No mate if I do such then it raise intial error i.e., it returns me the row equal to the number of AlbumId. In my case for **1 singer it returns me 3 rows since this singer have 3 ids**
@Pranay
If I  collect AlbumsId into 1 variable as you mentioned in your first comment, it returns 1 Singer row have 3 AlbumIds.. now I need to get the names of Albums matching to the ids that we have collected in the varialble