# Using multiple Join Methods instead of join in Linq To SQL

Tags: c#, join, linq-to-sql

I want to using join method for the following queryin Linq To SQL
**What works correctly:**

```
var db = new DatabaseDataContext();
db.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false;
var q = from p in db.Persons
        join c in db.Contacts on c.personId equal p.Id
        join j in db.Jobs on j.personId equal p.Id
        select SetPersonItems(p,c,j) ;
```

and what is SetPersonItems:

```
private Person SetPersonItems(Person p, Contact c, Job j)
{ 
   p.Contact = c;
   p.Job = j;
   return p;
}
```

**What I need:**
Now I would like using of Join Method for the above query. Like:

```
var q = db.Persons.Join<......>(db.Contacts,...).Join<....>(db.Jobs,...).Select....
```

*p.s. Later I will create a dynamic method for the above Multiple Join (Join methods)*

Comment: So what's the actual question here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to perform Join between multiple tables in LINQ lambda](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720225/how-to-perform-join-between-multiple-tables-in-linq-lambda)

Comment: You want to implement eager loading? What is the point of your SetPersonItems function?

Comment: @Rahul, Question is converting first query (which used join) to second type which using Join method. Actually I couldn't get correct result for second type (using Join method instead of using join)

Comment: @Pleun,  yes! and `SetPersonItems` will add `Job` and `Contact` properties to the `Person` rows and at end we have rows of Persons include their Contact and Job.

Comment: @Hamid, go through MSDN documentation and you will get the answer.

Comment: You should look into datacontext LoadWith options to force eager loading a