# Nhibernate fluent mirroring

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Someone know how i can mirror between two tables.
I mean, i want that every data that enter to table A will enter automatically to table B.

I want to do this without call twice to save function for each table

Thank you

Comment: I guess you mean Auditing. Take a look at [Envers](https://envers.bitbucket.io/)

Comment: I will read more about this, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by looking into linq for joining tables. Please see this [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720225/how-to-perform-join-between-multiple-tables-in-linq-lambda) as it seems that someone else had a similar issue. Cheers!

Comment: This is less what i need, because my problem is in relations table that i want to mirror between them, and the relation table is created automatically so i cant to do it like this