# How to write a join which defines two table aliases?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, join, asp.net-web-api

Our `.NET Web API` controller's `GET` method has `entity framework` `join` logic which looks like this:

```
from myTableAlias in db.myTable

join ruAlias in db.ru
on myTableAlias.someField equals ruAlias.someField

where...
```

The above `join` allows me to set an alias for one table - the `db.ru` table. On the line below `join`, **what if I don't want to reference `myTableAlias`, but rather want to define a new alias to a third table and `join` with that?** Something like:

```
from myTableAlias in db.myTable

join ruAlias in db.ru, thirdTableAlias in db.thirdTable
on thirdTableAlias.someField equals ruAlias.someField

where...
```

Obviously `thirdTableAlias` can't be defined in this way. I tried adding another `from` keyword like `from thirdTableAlias in db.thirdTable`, but I was informed that I shouldn't use multiple `from`s here.

How can I define both `ruAlias` and `thirdTableAlias` in this example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720225/how-to-perform-join-between-multiple-tables-in-linq-lambda

Comment: So you don't want a join between `myTableAlias` and either of the other two tables? So you want a cartesian product or cross join there?