# c# linq Query how to write multiple And condition

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

This is My Query in Linq

```
 VAR x = FROM n IN _db.tbl_maint_activity_material_details
            JOIN availablity IN _db.tbl_maint_item_availability ON n.mamd_lotno equals availablity.mia_lot_no && n. ////
```

Here im not able to countine my Code Please Help me 
This is My SQL query

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl_maint_activity_material_details AS _material
       JOIN tbl_maint_item_availability AS availablity
            ON  _material.mamd_maint_item_id = availablity.mia_maint_item_id
            AND _material.mamd_lotno = availablity.mia_lot_no
WHERE  _material.mamd_status = 24
```

Comment: Or: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9720225/how-to-perform-join-between-multiple-tables-in-linq-lambda

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish that, you have to build an object and use `equals`.

Something like:

```
on new { mia_lot_no = n.mamd_lotno, mamd_lotno = n.mamd_lotno  } equals new { mia_lot_no = availablity.mia_lot_no, mamd_lotno  = ... }
```

So that the `equals` will result `true` if the whole object is equal.