# Remove non-common items from list

Tags: c#, linq

I have two list of objects one of which has a different number of items. Now, if I do a:

```
 var result = list1.Except(list2);
```

That would give me the difference between the items that are in list1 and not in list2, right? What I'd like to do, if possible, is to remove from list1 all those items in the same step.
What I don't want to do is to have to loop through the "result" list and remove them from list1. Is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853526/using-linq-to-remove-objects-within-a-listt

Comment: I actually tried this: list1.RemoveAll(list1.Except(list2)); and that gives an error

Comment: @LuisGarcia - Are you looking for a one line statement? Why the aversion to a loop? Its easy enough to understand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `List.RemoveAll`:

```
list1.RemoveAll(t => !list2.Contains(t));
```

This does not need to create a new collection and it also needs only one loop to remove all items that are in list1 but not in list2. However, i assume that you have misunderstood how LINQ works. `Enumerable.Except` is implemented using deferred execution. That means it will not be executed until the `foreach`. `Except` is also very efficient with large lists since it's using a set approach.

Answer (score 6):

Tim's solution is correct, but has a runtime of O(list1.Length * list2.Length). When you use a `HashSet<T>` with a proper hash you get close to O(O(list1.Length + list2.Length) runtime. This is much faster when `list2` contains more than a handful of items.

The downside of my variant is that it needs to allocate the hashset and thus needs more memory.

```
var set2 = new HashSet<T>(list2);
list1.RemoveAll(item=>!set2.Contains(item));
```

Comment: This is the most efficient approach if memory doesn't matter, so +1.

Answer (score 0):

An less efficient alternative to [Tim's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18875544/211627) is a simple `Where` clause (kind of like a subquery in SQL). The benefit is you do not need to modify the original collection:

```
string[] list1 = new string[] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e" };
string[] list2 = new string[] { "c", "d", "e", "f", "g" };

var result = list1.Where( i => list2.Contains( i ) ).ToArray();
```

If you have very large datasets, I would still recommend Tim's approach.

Result:

> c
>   d
>   e

To use SQL terminology (to help with your googling), this is called an "inner join". In your case, this is a very simple problem since your input lists and result list are of the same type. If you wanted a more complex join between lists of different types, you may find this question helpful:

[inner join in linq to entities](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6176192/211627)

Comment: This is not efficient. It has the same downside as my approach on large lists since it's complexity is `O(list1.Length * list2.Length)`. But it also has to create a new array(note that `ToList` is more efficient than `ToArray`, OP has used lists anyway). OP is also not using Linq-To-Sql but Linq-To-Objects as the `Except` suggest.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - I've modified my post to address your concerns. I did not mean to suggest it was more efficient. Also, though the post was about LINQ to SQL, the syntax is equally valid for LINQ to Entities. I've found a different post which is more (superficially) on-topic