# Force inner join with many-to-many relationship entity framework

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5, linq-query-syntax

I have a many-to-many relationship setup in my database like so:

```
User
-------
Id (PK, Identity)
First
Last
...various other fields

Skill
-------
Id (PK, Identity)
Description

UserSkill
-----------
UserId (PK, FK on User.Id)
SkillId (PK, FK On Skill.Id)
```

When I run this LINQ query on the DbContext:

```
from u in Users 
from s in u.Skills 
where s.Id == 5 
select new 
{
    u.Id,
    s.Description
})
```

The SQL generated contains all inner joins which is what I want:

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[UserId] AS [UserId], 
[Extent2].[Description] AS [Description]
FROM  [dbo].[UserSkill] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[Skill] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[SkillId] = [Extent2].[Id]
WHERE 5 = [Extent2].[Id]
```

However, when I add a simple extra where clause:

```
from u in Users 
from s in u.Skills 
where s.Id == 5 
    && u.Last == "test"
select new 
{
    u.Id,
    s.Description
})
```

The SQL generated now uses a sub-query:

```
[Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
[Filter1].[Description] AS [Description]
FROM  [dbo].[User] AS [Extent1]
INNER JOIN  (SELECT [Extent2].[UserId] AS [UserId], [Extent3].[Description] AS [Description]
    FROM  [dbo].[UserSkill] AS [Extent2]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Skill] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent3].[Id] = [Extent2].[SkillId]
    WHERE 5 = [Extent3].[Id] ) AS [Filter1] ON [Extent1].[Id] = [Filter1].[UserId]
WHERE 'test' = [Extent1].[Last]
```

Maybe I am missing something, but I would think EF would just add another join back to the User table for this query and be able to do a where on User.Last instead of doing a sub-query.  Is there any way to force this kind of behavior?  Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

---

**UPDATE**

Cosmin, I am wanting the query to come out like this:

```
SELECT u.Id, s.Description
FROM [User] u INNER JOIN
        [UserSkill] us ON u.Id = us.UserId INNER JOIN
        [Skill] s ON us.SkillId = s.Id
WHERE s.Id = 2 AND u.Last = 'test'
```

Comment: Do you want your query to be something like: SELECT * FROM (SELECT * from Users where ...) Usr inner join Skill where ... ?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6176192/inner-join-in-linq-to-entities

Comment: Nathan, I don't see what is duplicate? That join does not look like a many-to-many as far as I can see. Can you please explain?

Comment: i dont have VS here with me: but to me it looks we can try something like this : 
dbcontext.users.where(x => x.id == 5).include("skills")

Comment: @Nathan Not a duplicate because in many-to-many, there's nothing in the entity model to join on

Comment: Have you profiled anything? You're not supposed to care about the SQL generated by your L2E provider, unless there's a performance problem.

Comment: Thanks qamar, but the include made the sql even crazier.  I haven't profiled the performance Stijin, and while the difference may in fact be minimal, direct inner joins are usually faster than joining on a sub-query.  My goal was to find out if that can be done, and whether I am doing something wrong with my linq query code or SQL DB setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this is an optimization that EF does not currently do. Personally, I'd stick with the sub query it generates unless performance becomes a problem.

But if you are willing to lose the direct navigation properties for User and Skill, you can model the intermediate table to get the query you are looking for.

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string First { get; set; }
    public string Last { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserSkill> UserSkills { get; set; }
}

public class UserSkill
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public User User { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Skill Skill { get; set; }

}

public class Skill
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserSkill> UserSkills { get; set; }
}
```

Then the following query will produce a join instead of subquery

```
 from x in db.UserSkills 
 where x.Skill.Id == 5 && x.User.Last == "test"
 select new {x.User.Id, x.Skill.Description};
```

Comment: Thanks Josh.  I was hoping to not have to go that route, but it looks like it is either that or just deal with the sub-query.

Answer (score 0):

@ryanulit, your issue is valid and it is an issue for all Linq to Entities. Please check the posted MS Forum's URL

[MS Forum's URL](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3a7f7141-9243-437f-84f2-a2fe18ba4222/very-inefficient-sql-generation-in-ef?forum=adodotnetentityframework)

Comment: -1 a discussion from September 2008, a month after the initial release of Entity Framework, is irrelevant to a question about EF 5.

Comment: @Stijn, The EF 5 has some advanced features only. This EF 5 still holds issue of adding extra join for every && operation. The answer given by Josh is a workaround to avoid this.