# LINQ Many-To-Many Where

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

How do I write an EF7 (Core) / SQL Friendly Many-To-Many LINQ Query?

Say for example I have many Friends that speak Many Languages, and I want to find all friends for a given set of languages.

```
class Friend
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }
    ICollection<FriendLanguage> Languages { get; set; }
}

class Language
{
    Guid { get; set; }
    ICollection<FriendLanguage> Friends { get; set; }
}

class FriendLanguage
{
    Friend { get; set; }
    Language { get; set; }
}
```

Given I have a set of language IDs `IEnumerable<Guid>`, I want to get back all the friends that speak those languages.

I tried this...

```
friends
    .Include(o => o.Languages).ThenInclude(o => o.Language)
    .SelectMany(o => o.Languages).Select(o => o.Language.Id)
    .Intersect(languages);
```

...but this only returns a reduced set of Guids...not entirely sure where to go from here, or even if I'm on the right path.

Comment: `friends.Include(o => o.Languages).ThenInclude(o => o.Language).Where(f => f.Languages.SelectMany(l => l.Language).Any(l => listOfLanguages.Contains(l.Guid)))`

Comment: @haim770 - That query will have severe performance issues, if it even executes.

Comment: @TravisJ, In EF 6 it generates a very reasonable SQL and it *does* execute.

Comment: @haim770 what about EF 7 (aka EF Core)?

Comment: Probably you can just select from `FriendLanguage` directly instead of usage `Friend` and  `Language` (see [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23398605/315935)) ? One should get clear INNER JOIN instead of sub-queries. I didn't verified that, but it seems so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to get the friends that speak **all** the languages from the list.

The most natural LINQ query expressing your requirement would be:

```
var friends = db.Friends
    .Include(o => o.Languages).ThenInclude(o => o.Language)
    .Where(o => languages.All(id => o.Languages.Any(fl => fl.Language.Id == id)));
```

Unfortunately it's not SQL friendly. In fact EF Core currently cannot translate it to SQL and will read the data in memory and do the filtering there.

So you can use this instead:

```
var friends = db.Friends
    .Include(o => o.Languages).ThenInclude(o => o.Language)
    .Where(o => o.Languages.Count(fl => languages.Contains(fl.Language.Id)) == languages.Count);
```

which translates to something like this:

```
SELECT [o].[Id]
FROM [Friends] AS [o]
WHERE (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [FriendLanguages] AS [fl]
    WHERE [fl].[LanguageId] IN ('6e64302f-24db-4717-a5fe-2cc61985ca3a', '2c216a63-1f6a-4fad-9105-d5f8ece3fa3c') AND ([o].[Id] = [fl].[FriendId])
) = @__languages_Count_1
ORDER BY [o].[Id]
```

If you indeed want the friends that speak **any** of the languages from the list, then the `Where` is simpler:

```
.Where(o => o.Languages.Any(fl => languages.Contains(fl.Language.Id)))
```

and the SQL is:

```
SELECT [o].[Id]
FROM [Friends] AS [o]
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [FriendLanguages] AS [fl]
    WHERE [fl].[LanguageId] IN ('ed3f85a7-e122-45dd-b0af-2020052d55a7', '4819cb7d-ad43-41a0-a3a1-979b7abc6265') AND ([o].[Id] = [fl].[FriendId]))
ORDER BY [o].[Id]
```

Comment: And if I wanted to check any language rather than all languages, then presumably I replace == languages.Count with > 0 ?

Comment: Answer updated. `Any` + `Contains` is pretty standard way of handling conditions on `many` side, the same was in EF6.